# Compute some expectations involving beta and gamma distributions

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, gamma-distribution

a) Let $X \sim {\text {Beta}}(a,b)$, with density $f(x) = \frac{x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}} {B (a,b)}$. Find the expectation of $X \ln X$ and $\frac{1}{X+1}.$

b) Let $Y \sim {\text {Gamma}}(\alpha,\beta)$, with density $g(y) = {\frac {\beta ^{\alpha }}{\Gamma (\alpha )}}y^{\alpha \,-\,1}e^{-\beta y}$. Find the expectation of $Y \ln Y$ and $\frac{1}{Y+1}.$

c) Assume $X,Y$ are independent. Find $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{XY+1}]$ and $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{Y-XY+1}]$.

I reduced my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364932/help-with-an-expectation-of-log-beta-or-gamma-function) to the above much simpler questions. Any help with this question will help the previous question as well. Any help with any of above expectation calculations will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please write the expressions of their pdf ... at least for Gamma (if same as wiki then put wiki link)... and also conditions on $a,b$ etc.

Comment: Conditions on parameters do seem important. If either X or Y concentrates probability near 0, then you need to investigate whether expectations of 1/X and 1/Y exist.

Comment: Thanks. I amended the question.

Comment: $E(1/(X+1))$ can be done by expanding $1/(X+1)$.

Comment: This question contains a more general solution to $E(1/(X+1))$ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277864/a-bound-based-on-jensens-inequality

Comment: To avoid confusion, the previous comment refers to the solution to $E(\frac{1}{Y+1})$, not $E(\frac{1}{X+1})$.

Comment: As presented, this issue has no connection with statistics. I have erased the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a computer algebra system?

Part (a): For $X \sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then here is the output generated by *mathStatica / Mathematica* to the first problem:

[image]

... where `HarmonicNumber[n]` denotes the $n^\text{th}$ harmonic number $H_n=\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$, and

[image]
where `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[a,b,c,z]` denotes ${_2}F{_1}(a,b;c;z) / \Gamma(c)$, and `Expect` is a *mathStatica* function (of which I am one of the authors).

---

Part (b): For $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ with pdf $g(y)$:

[image]

... you seek:

[image]

... where `EulerGamma` is Euler's constant (approx 0.577), and:

[image]

where `ExpInteralE[`$\alpha$, $\beta$ `]` is the exponential integral function $\int _1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^\alpha} e^{-\beta t} dt$

---

Part (c): Find $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{XY+1}]$ and $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{Y-XY+1}]$.

These two questions are essentially the same. To see this, note that if $X \sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$, then $(1-X) \sim \text{Beta}(b,a)$, and that $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{Y-XY+1}] = \Bbb E [\frac{1}{(1-X)Y+1}]$ which is thus also of form  $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{XY+1}]$ (just with the $X$ parameters swapped). So we only need to solve the first part.

Given independence, the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$, say $h(x,y) = f(x) g(y)$:

[image]

Then $\Bbb E [\frac{1}{XY+1}]$ is:

[image]

While this expression looks rather cumbersome, it appears to be correct, and works fine for non-integer parameter values. For instance, when ${a = 2.2, b = 3.3, \alpha = 4.1, \beta = 5.2}$, the above expression returns a value of 0.780101 for the expectation (which is consistent with Monte Carlo simulation).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
**$\ds{\Large\left.a\right)}$**
\begin{align}
&\bbox[13px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{a - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{b - 1} \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\,x\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
\left.{1 \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\,\partiald{}{\nu}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{a + \nu}\pars{1 - x}^{b - 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{1 \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\,\partiald{\mrm{B}\pars{a + \nu + 1,b}}{\nu}
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0} =
\left.{1 \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\,\partiald{}{\nu}
{\Gamma\pars{a + \nu + 1}\Gamma\pars{b} \over \Gamma\pars{a + \nu + 1 + b}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma\pars{b} \over
\Gamma\pars{a}\Gamma\pars{b}/\Gamma\pars{a + b}}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1 + a}\,{H_{a} - H_{a + b} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + a + b}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma\pars{a + b} \over
\Gamma\pars{a}}\bracks{%
a\,\Gamma\pars{a}\,{H_{a} - H_{a + b} \over \pars{a + b}\Gamma\pars{a + b}}} =
\bbx{{a \over a + b}\pars{H_{a} - H_{a + b}}}
\end{align}

> ---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[13px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{a - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{b - 1} \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}
\,{1 \over x + 1}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{b - 1}
\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}x}^{\,-1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \mrm{B}\pars{a,b}}\bracks{%
\mrm{B}\pars{a,b}\,\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{1,a;a + b;-1}} =
\bbx{\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{1,a;a + b;-1}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} is evaluated as an 'Euler Type' expression for the *Hypergeometric Function*: It's given in
>   [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).

---

**$\ds{\Large\left.b\right)}$**
\begin{align}
&\bbox[13px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\,y^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-\beta y}y\ln\pars{y}\,\dd y} =
{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\alpha + \nu}\expo{-\beta y}\,\dd y
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\partiald{}{\nu}\bracks{{1 \over \beta^{\alpha + \nu + 1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\alpha + \nu}\expo{-y}\,\dd y}_{\ \nu\ =\ 0} =
{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\partiald{}{\nu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\alpha + \nu + 1} \over
\beta^{\alpha + \nu + 1}}}_{\ \nu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\braces{%
-\beta^\pars{-1 - \alpha}\,\Gamma\pars{1 + \alpha}\bracks{\ln\pars{\beta} - H_{\alpha} + \gamma}} =
\bbx{{\alpha \over \beta}\bracks{H_{\alpha} - \gamma - \ln\pars{\beta}}}
\end{align}